# RPi 3 Python Script - NameError: name 'BluetoothSocket' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, bluetooth-socket

So I am relatively new to python scripting and I came across this code that is supposed to configure wifi over bluetooth between a raspberry pi and smart device. Unfortunately, I keep running into the error listed in the title. I was hoping someone can copy and run the code and enlighten me why i keep running into this error. All help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

from bluetooth import *

from wifi import Cell, Scheme

import subprocess

import time




wpa_supplicant_conf = "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"

sudo_mode = "sudo "


def wifi_connect(ssid, psk):

    # write wifi config to file
    f = open('wifi.conf', 'w')
    f.write('country=GB\n')
    f.write('ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev\n')
    f.write('update_config=1\n')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('network={\n')
    f.write('    ssid="' + ssid + '"\n')
    f.write('    psk="' + psk + '"\n')
    f.write('}\n')
    f.close()

    cmd = 'mv wifi.conf ' + wpa_supplicant_conf
    cmd_result = ""
    cmd_result = os.system(cmd)
    print cmd + " - " + str(cmd_result)


    # restart wifi adapter
    cmd = sudo_mode + 'ifdown wlan0'
    cmd_result = os.system(cmd)
    print cmd + " - " + str(cmd_result)

    time.sleep(2)

    cmd = sudo_mode + 'ifup wlan0'
    cmd_result = os.system(cmd)
    print cmd + " - " + str(cmd_result)

    time.sleep(10)

    cmd = 'iwconfig wlan0'
    cmd_result = os.system(cmd)
    print cmd + " - " + str(cmd_result)

    cmd = 'ifconfig wlan0'
    cmd_result = os.system(cmd)
    print cmd + " - " + str(cmd_result)

    p = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig', 'wlan0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    out, err = p.communicate()

    ip_address = "<Not Set>"

    for l in out.split('\n'):
        if l.strip().startswith("inet addr:"):
            ip_address = l.strip().split(' ')[1].split(':')[1]

    return ip_address



def ssid_discovered():

    Cells = Cell.all('wlan0')

    wifi_info = 'Found ssid : \n'

    for current in range(len(Cells)):
        wifi_info +=  Cells[current].ssid + "\n"


    wifi_info+="!"

    print wifi_info
    return wifi_info


def handle_client(client_sock) :

    # get ssid
    client_sock.send(ssid_discovered())
    print "Waiting for SSID..."


    ssid = client_sock.recv(1024)
    if ssid == '' :
        return

    print "ssid received"
    print ssid

    # get psk
    client_sock.send("waiting-psk!")
    print "Waiting for PSK..."


    psk = client_sock.recv(1024)
    if psk == '' :
        return

    print "psk received"

    print psk

    ip_address = wifi_connect(ssid, psk)

    print "ip address: " + ip_address

    client_sock.send("ip-addres:" + ip_address + "!")

    return



try:
    while True:

        server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
        server_sock,bind(("",PORT_ANY))
        server_sock.listen(1)

        port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

        uuid = "815425a5-bfac-47bf-9321-c5ff980b5e11"

        advertise_service( server_sock, "RaspberryPiServer",
                           service_id = uuid,
                           service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                           profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
                           protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ] 
                            )

        print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

        client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
        print "Accepted connection from ", client_info

        handle_client(client_sock)

        client_sock.close()
        server_sock.close()

        # finished config
        print 'Finished configuration\n'


except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):

    print '\nExiting\n'
```

This code outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 128, in <module>
    server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )

NameError: name 'BluetoothSocket' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Chris, fairly new to this so I didnt know how to format it properly. Any ideas why it is generating that error?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've never done Bluetooth programming. But there's no `bluetooth` module in the standard library. You should probably [edit] your question and tell us what library you're using, and probably your OS too since Bluetooth support is probably going to be OS-specific.

Comment: It is a project involving Raspberry Pi 3 which have bluetooth libraries that can be installed. Im not quite sure of all the libraries involved with this project but they are incorporated in the top of the script.

Comment: You _import_ them at the top of the script. But `from bluetooth import *` and `from wifi import Cell, Scheme` won't work out of the box with Python. Some other libraries must be installed, and without knowing what they are this question is very difficult to answer.

Comment: I thought I installed all libraries that would ever be required for my project but I'll install look around and install more libraries in the hopes that it will fix my problem.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. _You_ probably _have_ installed them. (Otherwise you'd get an error during `import`.) But _I_ don't know what they are. It's very hard to answer without knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us your python version ?

Just type:

```
$ python --version
```

`bluetooth` lib seems to be present. But not `BluetoothSocket`: try to install bluez and python-bluez

```
$ sudo apt-get install bluez
$ sudo apt-get install python-bluez
```